# Reautenticar con google

Tags: flutter, firebase-auth, auth

Tengo un problema con la reautenticación con google, ya que requiero cambiar información sensible como la contraseña o correo y me pide "requires-recent-login" que este logueado recientemente, estoy intentando varios métodos, para poder reautenticarme con el proveedor de google (ya que el usuario no posee contraseña ya que solo tiene el proveedor de autenticación de google para ese punto), pero algunos no me funcionan, por ejemplo he intentado:

```
final firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
final user = firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
await user.reauthenticateWithPopup(firebase_auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

me arroja un este error "reauthenticateWithPopup() is not implemented"

Intenté hacer el sign in nuevamente, pero al querer hacer el cambio de contraseña o correo, me sigue arrojando "requires-recent-login"

```
     final user = firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
     final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
        final googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        final googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
        final credential = firebase_auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Y el último que he intentado es con este código

```
    final user = firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
    final provider = firebase_auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    await user.reauthenticateWithProvider(provider);
```

Este me envía a un webview donde están las cuentas que tengo registradas, pero al presionar la que es de la cuenta, me retorna mandándome el mensaje:
"web-context-canceled"

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848], locale en-US)     
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default
      components
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```